# Is it possible to load core file (generated by arm processor) in x86 machine?

Tags: gdb, cross-compiling, coredump

I have memory constraint in my embedded device based on arm architecture.
One program crashed at some point and generated core file. Now i am not able load this core file in the same device as i don't have further memory to copy souce files and debug executable (without strip).

Is it possible to load this core file on linux machine (ubuntu, x86 machine) to find crash location ?

some thing like on x86 linux machine
#gdb <arm_exe_name> --core <arm_core_file> --target arm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to load this core file on linux machine (ubuntu, x86 machine) to find crash location ?

Yes: you need to binary and any shared libraries it used, the `core` file, and a GDB cross-debugger built for your target host, or with multiarch support.

Ubuntu provides [gdb-multiarch package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gdb-multiarch) which should just work. Something like:

```
gdb -iex 'set sysroot /path/to/embedded/root' /path/to/exe /path/to/core
(gdb) where
```

Comment: The gdb-multiarch worked fine for me, except for some reason it did not support the `--sysroot` command line argument. Instead I used `-ix` to provide command file and `set sysroot ...` from there.

Comment: on Debian I installed `gcc make gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu binutils-aarch64-linux-gnu binutils-multiarch binutils-multiarch-dbg binutils-multiarch-dev gdb-multiarch` but `gdb-multiarch  --batch -nx --ex 'set architecture aarch64' -iex 'set sysroot /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu'  <binary> -c <coredump>` exits immediately, only issuing an error about missing libmusl headers `[New LWP 33049]...[New LWP 30509] ... 29      ./arch/aarch64/syscall_arch.h: No such file or directory.` . What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `warning: Can't open file /work/ArangoDB/build/bin/arangod during file-backed mapping note processing` and `warning: Can't open file /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC during file-backed mapping note processing` is printed, though if I create the binary path and copy it over.